# error in DbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working in 5 projects under one Solution and am working in MVC 4.5 . when i create an instance of the DbContext inherited Class then it give an error

The type System.Data.Entity.DbContext is defined in an assembly that is not referenced You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'"

I added the Assemblies to my web.config file 
should i Use the Same PulicKeyToken and Version the same as i got in the error Message . if you have any other solution , it will be fine . I also added the references of System.Data.Entity  but the problem is the same

Comment: Looks like something gets messed up with EF dlls! Did you tried to reinstall the EF package using Nuget? Take look and let me now if works!

Comment: yeah you are right please post the Answer to tick it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like something gets messed up with EF dlls! Did you tried to reinstall the EF package using Nuget? Take look and let me know if works!

Hope this help you!